# Assign one value to multiple names in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am fairly new to JSON and was wondering if there is a way to have a name/value pair with multiple names.  I want to be able to search for either name and retrieve the same value without having to change the value in two separate places.

Something like this:

```
{"someName & someOtherName" : "singleValue"}
```

And if there isn't a way to do this natively, are there any JSON preproccesors?  Maybe something like SASS where I can create a variable and use that variable to assign a single value throughout the file?

```
$singleValue: true;

something: $singleValue;
somethingElse: $singleValue
```

Comment: There is no way to do this natively. Why did you tag this with JavaScript if it is about JSON? You are not confusing JSON with JS object literals, are you?

Answer (score 0):

> And if there isn't a way to do this natively

There isn't.

> are there any JSON preproccesors?

I'm not aware of any (and software recommendation questions are off-topic for Stackoverflow anyway), but writing one in the language of your choice wouldn't be difficult.

Building a data structure from some variables and then generating JSON is a trivial enough problem that you could just write a simple script in just about any language you liked instead of using a dedicated preprocessor.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.18;
use JSON;

my $value = "singleValue";

my %data = (
        someName => $value,
        someOtherName => $value
    );

print JSON::encode_json(\%data);
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs

var value = "singleValue";

var data = {
        someName: value,
        someOtherName: value
    };

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```